# Is it possible to have the devise user signed in automatically after signing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have been trying for three days now and i could not get it fixed.

After the user "signs up" it would redirect to a verification page where the user enters an SMS token (a number digit) and then the user is confirmed when the correct SMS token is entered.

verification_code_input.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user, url: verifications_path do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :verification_code_confirmation %><br />
  <div><%= f.number_field :verification_code_confirmation %></div>
  <div><%= f.submit 'Verify' %></div>

<% end %>
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
  super
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
   p = [('0'..'9')].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
  @user.verification_code = (0...6).map{ p[rand(p.length)] }.join

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
#      render text: "Thank you! You will receive an SMS shortly with verification instructions."

      # Instantiate a Twilio client
      client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

      # Create and send an SMS message
      client.account.sms.messages.create(
        from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
        to: "+6#{@user.phone}",
        body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please enter code #{@user.verification_code} in the Clixster Store registration page."
      )

        format.html { redirect_to verification_code_input_path }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end

 end

def update
  super
end

 def verification_code_input
   # @code = User.find(current_user.id).verification_code
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
   end
 end

 def verification
   @user =  params[:id].blank? ? current_user : User.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     if @user.verify_and_save(params[:user])
       format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for Signing up! Have a great time on our store."}
     else
       format.html { render action: "verification_code_input" }
     end
   end
 end


end
```

routes.rb

```
get "verifications/new" => "verifications#new"
  post "verifications" => "verifications#create"
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :verification_code_confirmation, :phone
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def verify_and_save(attributes)
    self.assign_attributes attributes
    if self.verification_code == self.verification_code_confirmation
      self.verified = true
      self.verification_code = nil
      self.save
    else
      self.errors.add(:verification_code_confirmation)
      false
    end
  end

end
```

EDIT: Add the error that i had.

I have the error:

```
undefined method `verify_and_save' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Uh, not related, but `[('0'..'9')].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten` is better written `('0'..'9').to_a`.

Comment: What error you are getting exactly..?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to bypass,

after verifying user with code, try this

```
sign_in @user, :bypass => true
```

then use

```
redirect_to root_path
```

Comment: I had an error - "Could not find a valid mapping for nil"

The reason is after signing up, the user doesn't get "signed in" to get the "current_user" information.

Answer (score 0):

In your create method:

```
sign_in(:user, @user)
```

Then redirect to wherever you want.